# Lilypond: Offset piano sustain off permanently

Tags: lilypond

With Lilypond, is it possible to move the "sustain off" allways by a fixed offset?

I can tweak it with `-\tweak X-offset 1` like this:

```
\relative c' { c8 c c\sustainOn c-\tweak X-offset 1\sustainOff c c c c }
```

[image]

Question: can I obtain the X-offset of *all* my `sustainOff` without having to add the tweak everytime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can redefine the sustain off at the top of your code:

```
sustainOff =
    #( define-event-function () ()
        #{
            -\tweak X-offset #1  %%%  Adjusts this number 
            -#(make-span-event 'SustainEvent STOP)
        #}
    )

\relative c' { c8 c c\sustainOn c\sustainOff c c c c }
```

[image: lilypond output with sustain off redefined]

Comment: Awesome! I searched through the internal program code and had this idea, because I’m pretty sure I did this to something else (much simpler), but I wouldn’t have come up with something this neat. OOC, if you do a `\sustainOn` on the note following the `Off`, it collides with the mark. Without this tweak, LilyPond automatically resizes width between notes to prevent that from happening. Any ideas for preserving that behavior?

Comment: If you put the `\sustainOff` and `\sustainOn` on the same note LilyPond spaces them appropriately (but ignores the tweak for some reason).

Comment: Personally I usually use `\set Staff.pedalSustainStyle = #'mixed`, which also works pretty well.  But this doesn't use the pretty asterisk.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the use of a support function and  "refactoring" this way is highly recommended any time you have a repeated need for a particular effect.  This is taught (I hope!!!) in most intro-software programming courses.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to have a dedicated Dynamics staff for just the pedal markings. Instead of including the pedals in, say, the left-hand notation, you can include them separately. One positive to this, in my opinion, is that the pedal markings are all notated at a uniform distance from the staff, as opposed to them being engraved at several distances from the staff.

Using this separate pedal staff, a simple `\override SustainPedal.X-offset = #3` (or whatever distance you want) should do the trick.

```
\version "2.20.0"
\language "english"

right = \relative c'' {
  c4 c c c |
  c c c c |
}

left = \relative c' {
  c4 c c c |
  c c c c |
}

pedal = {
  \override SustainPedal.X-offset = #3
  s4\sustainOn s\sustainOff s4 s |
  s s\sustainOn s\sustainOff s |
}

\score {
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff = "right" \right
    \new Staff = "left" { \clef bass \left }
    \new Dynamics = "pedals" \pedal
  >>
  \layout { }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the question is about only the "off." I think your solution affects both the "on" and "off."

Comment: @Neal Oh, dang it...you're right, of course. I'll think about this and see if I have a better idea.

Comment: (Elements in Space beat me to that better idea. Upvote their answer!)